# Address family not supported when sending data to multiple clients UDP

Tags: c++, c, linux, networking, udp

I am currently writing a program in linux where:

1. client sends a "password" to the server
2. server waits for n people to send the password and records the address of the sender
3. after n messages are received, a start message is sent back to the senders.

The problem is when I try to send "start" back to the clients I get an Illegal seek error (ERROR in sendto: Illegal seek). And only the first client receives the start message (`clientaddrs[0]`)

Note: after 30 minutes of testing, the error has now become: Address family not supported by protocol.(absolutely nothing in the code has changed)

Here is my code (I've pasted a minimal reproduceable example)

To reproduce the problem:

1. run the server code with arguments: 8080
2. enter 2 at the prompt
3. run the client code on two different with argument: 127.0.0.1 8080
4. choose two different passcodes and enter them when prompted by the client

Server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>

#define TO_CLI_BUF_SIZE 32
#define FROM_CLI_BUF_SIZE 8

void printAddr(){ // for printing my ip

  struct ifaddrs * ifAddrStruct=NULL;
  struct ifaddrs * ifa=NULL;
  void * tmpAddrPtr=NULL;

  getifaddrs(&ifAddrStruct);

  for (ifa = ifAddrStruct; ifa != NULL; ifa = ifa->ifa_next) {
    if (!ifa->ifa_addr) {
      continue;
    }
    if (ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) { // check it is IP4
      // is a valid IP4 Address
      tmpAddrPtr=&((struct sockaddr_in *)ifa->ifa_addr)->sin_addr;
      char addressBuffer[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
      inet_ntop(AF_INET, tmpAddrPtr, addressBuffer, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
      printf("%s IP Address %s\n", ifa->ifa_name, addressBuffer); 
    } else if (ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET6) { // check it is IP6
      // is a valid IP6 Address
      tmpAddrPtr=&((struct sockaddr_in6 *)ifa->ifa_addr)->sin6_addr;
        char addressBuffer[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
      inet_ntop(AF_INET6, tmpAddrPtr, addressBuffer, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
      printf("%s IP Address %s\n", ifa->ifa_name, addressBuffer); 
    } 
  }
  if (ifAddrStruct!=NULL) freeifaddrs(ifAddrStruct);
}



int main(int argc, char ** argv){

  //seed rand
  srand(time(NULL));

  int sockfd; // socket
  int port; // my port to listen on
  struct sockaddr_in serveraddr; // server's address
  struct sockaddr_in clientaddrs[4];
  socklen_t clientLens[4];
  int currentAddrMax = 0;
  struct hostent * hostp; //host info
  char * hostaddrp; // host adddr string
  char toClientBuf[TO_CLI_BUF_SIZE];
  char fromClientBuf[FROM_CLI_BUF_SIZE];


  if(argc != 2){
    perror("usage: file <port>");
    exit(1);
  }
  port = atoi(argv[1]);

  // create socket
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if(sockfd<0){
    perror("ERROR: opening socket.");
    exit(1);
  }

  //int option = 1;
  //setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const void *)&option, sizeof(int));


  //internet stuff
  bzero((char*) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
  serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  serveraddr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)port);

  if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0){
    perror("ERROR on bind");
    exit(1);
  }



  int playerKeys[4];
  int playerJoined[4];
  printf("(you can enter 1,2,3 or 4)\n");
  printf("Enter amount of players: \n");
  int amountPlayers = 0;
  scanf("%d",&amountPlayers);
  // hacky way to clear screen
  printf("\033[H\033[J");
  printAddr();
  printf("PORT: %d\n", port);
  printf("player| key| in\n");
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    bool keyExists = true;
    while (keyExists == true ){
      playerKeys[i] = rand()%10000;
      keyExists = false;
      for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        if(playerKeys[i] == playerKeys[j]){
          keyExists = true;
        }
      }
    }

    printf("%d     |%04d|",i+1, playerKeys[i]);
    if(playerJoined[i] == 1){
      printf(" o\n");
    }else{
      printf(" x\n");
    }
    fflush(stdin);
  } 
  for(int i = 0; i < amountPlayers;i++){

    bzero(fromClientBuf, FROM_CLI_BUF_SIZE);

    int n = recvfrom(sockfd, fromClientBuf,FROM_CLI_BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &clientaddrs[currentAddrMax], &(clientLens[currentAddrMax]));
    //TODO store senders 
    if(n>0){
      int key = (fromClientBuf[0]-'0')*1000; //TODO change the way keys are extracted.
      key += (fromClientBuf[1]-'0')*100;
      key += (fromClientBuf[2]-'0')*10;
      key += (fromClientBuf[3]-'0');
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if(playerKeys[i] == key && playerJoined[i] == 0){
          playerJoined[i] = 1;
          currentAddrMax++;
        }
      }

      printf("\033[H\033[J");
      printAddr();
      printf("PORT: %d\n", port);
      printf("player| key| in\n");
      for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("%d     |%04d|",i+1, playerKeys[i]);
        if(playerJoined[i] == 1){
          printf(" o\n");
        }else{
          printf(" x\n");
        }
      }
      // decode key


    }
  }
  //TODO finished waiting for all senders. send them start signal
  //MAY BE USEFULL:n = sendto(sockfd, toClientBuf, strlen(toClientBuf), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, clientlen);

  strcpy(toClientBuf, "start");
  for(int j = 0; j < currentAddrMax; j++){
    int n = sendto(sockfd, toClientBuf, strlen(toClientBuf), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddrs[j], (clientLens[j]));
    if(n < 0) {
      perror("ERROR in sendto");
      printf("%d\n",j);
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  // wait for connections
  //main loop
  //set some options 

  struct timeval read_timeout;
  read_timeout.tv_sec = 0;
  read_timeout.tv_usec = 100;
  if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,&read_timeout,sizeof(read_timeout)) < 0) {
    perror("Error with options");
  }

  printf("start loop\n");


  return 0;

}
```

client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 


#define FROM_SER_BUF_SIZE 32
#define TO_SER_BUF_SIZE 8

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  int sockfd, portno, n;
  socklen_t serverlen;
  struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
  struct hostent *server;
  char *hostname;


  char toServerBuf[TO_SER_BUF_SIZE];
  char fromServerBuf[FROM_SER_BUF_SIZE];

  if (argc != 3) {
    perror("usage: filename <hostname> <port>\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  hostname = argv[1];
  portno = atoi(argv[2]);

  // create socket

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0) {
    perror("ERROR: opening sockets\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  // get host
  server = gethostbyname(hostname);
  if (server == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host as %s\n", hostname);
    exit(0);
  }

  // build server's internet address

  bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
  serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
  (char *)&serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
  serveraddr.sin_port = htons(portno);

  bzero(toServerBuf, TO_SER_BUF_SIZE);
  int key = 0;
  printf("Please enter your key: ");

  scanf("%d",&key);
  if(key > 9999 || key < 0){
    printf("INVALID KEY\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  toServerBuf[0] = key/1000 + '0';
  toServerBuf[1] = (key%1000)/100 + '0';
  toServerBuf[2] = (key%100)/10 +'0';
  toServerBuf[3] = key%10 + '0';

  serverlen = sizeof(serveraddr);

  n = sendto(sockfd, toServerBuf, strlen(toServerBuf), 0, ( struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, serverlen);

  if (n < 0){
    perror("ERROR: sendto\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  //TODO wait for server to get send start signal
  bzero(fromServerBuf, FROM_SER_BUF_SIZE);
  n = recvfrom(sockfd, fromServerBuf, FROM_SER_BUF_SIZE, 0,( struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, &serverlen);

  printf("wow we got here");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: One unique feature of UDP is that you have no guarantees whatsoever that anything will happen, when you send and receive UDP datagrams. You must be prepared to handle any error, at any time, and you have no guarantees that anything you attempt to send on a UDP socket will actually go anywhere. And when you get an error, there's nothing you can do to avoid it. That, after all, is the entire reason for UDP. If you want a reliable connection, use TCP.

Comment: Are you by chance trying to call `lseek` on a socket?

Comment: I would expect an error "Illegal seek" if you performed a `lseek` on a socket file descriptor, not as a result of `sendto`. Maybe the error occurs only in combination with the code not shown in the question. Try to create a [mcve]

Comment: "Illegal seek" (`ESPIPE`) is a very strange error code to get from `sendto`. It's not listed in the documentation, either.

Comment: @dbush No I haven't called it. However, after 30 minutes of me trying to fix it, the error has now become "Address family not supported by protocol". I will edit my post to match this

Comment: You have Undefined Behavior somewhere in your program. You probably overwrite some memory, which leads to random behavior.

Comment: @WEPIOD The error is probably in the parts of your code that you don't show in the question. Try to reduce your program to the minimum while still allowing it to be compiled and run. Probably you will come to a version that no longer shows the error. Enabling and fixing compiler warnings and running your program with `valgrind` may also help.

Comment: How you created the socket `sockfd` ?

Comment: @Bodo thanks for the tip. I've pasted an example

Comment: @VillageTech I've pasted an example of my code

Comment: @WEPIOD What command line arguments and input values do you use to reproduce the problem? From the source code I can see that I can call the programs like `./server 12345` and `./client localhost 12345`. In the server program I entered `1`, and I started 1 client instance and tried the 1st key shown by the server. Then the server prints "start loop" and exits. I cannot see any error.

Comment: @WEPIOD When I run the server program with `strace` I can see `lseek(0, -1, SEEK_CUR)                  = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)` mixed with the output of the player keys. This is a result of `fflush(stdin);`. When I remove this function call I no longer see the `lseek(0, ...)`. Did you mean to use `fflush(stdout);`? Maybe you call `perror` when no error occurred in the function call before it, and it prints the error message corresponding to the old value of `errno` which was set by the `lseek` on stdin. To avoid using wrong `errno` values you could set `errno = 0;` before calling `sendto`.

Comment: @Bodo As your second comment, it does seem that is the case. I must have changed the ordering of the print and I no longer see the seek error. Yes, the program works when only 1 user is connected. The problem arises with more than one users. I used 3 seperate terminals on the same computer to test. I have also tried to use 2 different computers to test and I get the same result.

Comment: @WEPIOD Please [edit] your question and add this information there. Please describe what exactly you do to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just tried the programs with 4 clients. I started `./server 12345` and entered `4`, then started `./client localhost 12345` in 4 terminal windows and entered one of the keys each. The server program prints "start loop" and exits without any error after entering the keys in all 4 client instances.

Comment: @Bodo Thank you for this information. I suspected it had something to do with my computer instead of my code. I will look into it. I've asked another friend to test on his computer as well.

Comment: @Bodo may I ask what Linux distro you use?

Comment: @WEPIOD I tested this on Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: @Bodo could you try compiling with clang++, go through the prompts and let me know if there are any errors with sendto? When I compile with clang it works but not with clang++ or g++ and my main program uses c++

Comment: Because of the C++ include `#include <chrono>` in the server I can't use a C compiler. With `g++` and `clang++` I get different behavior, and it depends on compiling with debug information or not. Sometimes I see `recvfrom` in the server returning `-1 EINVAL`, sometimes I see no reaction after entering the key in the client. `valgrind` reports passing uninitialized memory to syscalls, e.g. after `Syscall param sendto(tolen) contains uninitialised byte(s)` I see your error message `ERROR in sendto: Invalid argument`. Make sure all arguments are correct. Probably you have undefined behavior.

Comment: @Bodo Thank you. I'm trying to compile the longer version of my code which needs clang++. I can't seem to find an answer to fix my current problem. I think I will ask another question about the different behaviour between clang and clang++ tomorrow

Comment: I suggest to run your program with `valgrind` and fix all reported problems.

Comment: @Bodo Thank you. It seemed that the problem valgrind pointed out was the problem. I will edit my answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with g++. No idea why g++ doesn't work however, once I switched to clang all my errors went away. However, clang++ does not work either.

Edit: There was a problem with the clientaddr length found with valgrind. Turns out in the array for client legnths (for my example), we must first initialize it with the line

`clientLens[currentAddrMax] = sizeof(clientaddrs[currentAddrMax]);`

As Bodo mentions, we must always initialize the client length otherwise there will be unspecified behaviour.

Comment: It has nothing to do with using an array. See man page: https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom  *`ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags, struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);` ... The argument `addrlen` is a value-result argument, which the caller should initialize before the call to the size of the buffer associated with `src_addr`, and modified on return to indicate the actual size of the source address. The returned address is truncated if the buffer provided is too small; in this case, `addrlen` will return a value greater than was supplied to the call.*

Comment: ... If you don't initialize `addrlen`, the function will use the uninitialized value which is undefined behavior. The value that happens to be found there may depend on the compiler, so the result of this undefined behavior may vary with different compilers.